# How to terminate a python asyncio event_loop when all tasks have completed

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, concurrency, python-asyncio

Ok so basically I need clarification RE: how to use the `asyncio.run_until_complete(Future)` function.

After adding 3 tasks to my loop I attempt to create a `Future`"done callback" using the `asyncio.wait()` function.

### In the following code, my `event_loop.close()` never gets run:

```
import asyncio

async def repeat_message(message, interval_seconds, max_iters=10):
    iters = 0
    while True:
        print(message)
        if iters >= max_iters:
            return 'Complete.'
        iters += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(interval_seconds)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    message_A = "xXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXx"
    interval_A = 0.5
    message_B = "I LOVE"
    interval_B = 1
    message_C = "EXPLOSIONS!"
    interval_C = 1.5

    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    task_A = event_loop.create_task(repeat_message(message_A, interval_A))
    task_B = event_loop.create_task(repeat_message(message_B, interval_B))
    task_C = event_loop.create_task(repeat_message(message_C, interval_C))

    completed = event_loop.create_future()
    completed.add_done_callback(asyncio.wait([task_A, task_B, task_C], loop=event_loop))
    try:
        event_loop.run_until_complete(completed)
    finally:
        event_loop.close()
    # Never prints.
    print('DONE')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what `gather` is for. Get rid of your `completed` future, and use `gather` this way:

```
event_loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(task_A, task_B, task_C))
```

What you've written here creates a `Future` and configures it so that when the future completes, *then* it will wait for the tasks. But you never complete the future (with `set_result()` for instance). `Future` isn't really about running things asynchronously. It's just a data structure that represents "some future value that will be provided by someone eventually calling `set_result()` or raising an exception with `set_exception()`." That turns out to often be useful for asynchronous work, but it isn't itself a coroutine.

Comment: Ok awesome! That worked (& makes sense!) Thank you! 

This actually sheds a lot of light on some questions I had about why `Futures` & `Tasks` need to be distinct entities. 
Correct the recapitulation if I'm wrong but: Whereas a `Task` must necessarily be non-blocking, instances of its superclass `Future` don't need to be & this makes them useful as control structures. <--yah?

Comment: What if you have a list of tasks, instead of individual variables? I tried this and it throws an error "unhasable type: 'list' "